# How do I determine what Registry Keys a GPO modifies?

Tags: group-policy, windows-registry

It seems like such a simple question, but after hours of googling I can not find a way to correlate a GPO policy and a registry key that it would modify.

Does anyone have a way to decrypt them?

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays most group policies are based on [ADMX templates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/group-policy/create-and-manage-central-store). Since they are XML files, you can see their content with a text editor and look at the `registryKey` and `registryValueName` attributes (the schema is documented here: [ADMX Schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-gpreg/81d92810-a6d2-4301-a607-b3ba34dc2989))

However, as the files can easily be parsed, we can find websites that did the job and provides that kind of information, for example: https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/

Be aware that deploying Group Policies by manually editing registry keys is not supported and may lead to inconsistent behavior.